# ts class validator for dictionary

Tags: typescript, validation, dto, class-transformer

I have a class

```
type someType = string | number | boolean | someType[];

class someClass {
  [key: string]: {
    value: someType;
  }
}

class someDto {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  public myValue: someClass;
}
```

Could I create validation for `someClass` using class-transformer?

Comment: pls provide reproducable example